# Why String.indexOf function in Java take a int parameter to represent a char?

Tags: java, casting, char, int, indexof

I am new to Java programing, and I am confused when using the `String.IndexOf(int ch)` in my code.

For example, I want to find the first occurrence of `'-'` in a string `"abc-def-ghi"`.

so here is my code:

```
String test = "abc-def-ghi";
int firstOcc = test.IndexOf('-');
```

This code is working fine.

However, my question is, why `String.IndexOf()` function takes a `int` parameter as a `char`?

Is there any benefit to writing code as `IndexOf(int ch)` instead of `IndexOf(char ch)`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @duffymo - Um, the signature of the method is [`String.indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29). OP is asking why the arg is `int` and not `char`.

Comment: @Stobor - you are right. I wonder how I didn't see this post before I post my question....

Comment: My mistake - I misread it.